# javascript function not changing word-spacing

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make my nav link word-spacing reduce with smaller screen sizes. I know you can do it other ways using media queries for example but I am trying to learn javascript. Where am I missing?

```
<script>
    function navresize() {
       var w = window.outerWidth;
       if(w < 1000) {
       document.getElementsByTagName("nav").style.word-spacing = "3";
       };
    };
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("nav").style["word-spacing"] = "3";`

Comment: You should get into the habit of running your code with the JavaScript Console open (press F12).  It reports useful errors about this sort of thing.

Comment: Why not use CSS3 media-queries for this?

Comment: @howderek I'm trying to understand and learn javascript mainly.

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thanks but it's still not working. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hyphens aren't allowed in javascript dot notation, as they are also used for subtraction, you'd have to use either bracket notation or camelcase

```
element.style.wordSpacing = "3";
```

or

```
element.style['word-spacing'] = "3";
```

alto note that `getElementsByTagName` gets a nodelist, not a single element, so you have to access the element as well, and you generally want to use the units for the value

```
document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0].style.wordSpacing = "3px";
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that. Still not working for some reason though. Any other ideas? Cheers

Comment: And you are actually calling the `navresize` function somewhere ?

Comment: Yes, I have <body onload="navresize()">

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript you should use `element.style.wordSpacing`, since `-` means substract.